# How to load a CSS style sheet

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, css, frontend

So I basically got my own whole css layout and I want to change the layout of my magento frontend. I've looked into this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050668/how-to-apply-css-to-magento-cms-page but it's not loading my css in. I did this:

I added to Custom Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>csstest/style.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

and in my html editor I got this:

```
<div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="header_2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Css just in case:

```
.header{
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
height:15%;

/*border-radius:12px; */
background-color:white;
}

.header_2{
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
height:5%;
background-color:grey;
font-size:200%;
}
```

My style.css is in this directory:`/skin/frontend/default/csstest` I also tried to put it in: `skin/frontend/default/default/css`

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: afaik it's `<name>` not `<stylesheet>`.

Comment: have you not, by mistake, set a custom directory for CSS in System > Configuration > General > Design?

Answer (score 1):

Better use this syntax:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>csstest/style.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: It's still not showing my divs...

Comment: Are you missing the divs or the CSS styles for the divs?

Comment: I editted my question. I posted the code of my css and html editor.

Comment: Check in your browser if the CSS file is loading (check the link to the CSS file too), if the html code for the divs is appearing, empty Magento Cache, Browser Cache and so on...

Comment: When I press CTRL + U, it doesn't show link rel="stylesheet" style.css. The css file isn't in it. The html code is showing yes. I tried emptying the caches and it didn't do anything.

Comment: add this xml in <default> </default> tag
liike:
     <default>
    <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>csstest/style.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
</default>

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why are you not using a local xml and local css combo.  Also, have you updated your configuration to pull from the right design package and themes?

Its in System > General > Design >

Package should be where the files is loaded from initially.  Normally set to default theme package.  And theme is if you have created a new theme folder.  This needs to match exactly where you are loading you templates / skins / layouts and all lower case.

Lastly, I think your syntax is slightly wrong for the xml file.  Here is some more info about local xml and syntax.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156808/magento-custom-css-overridden-by-parent-css-using-local-xml